# Python e-mail attachment as xlsx doesnot work when I set name as a variable

Tags: email, smtp, attachment

I would like to send auto-mails to from time to time, and attach an excel file to the mail. It's okay if I write the name of the excel file straight ahead, however if I link it to a variable , what happens is a formatless file attached.[e-mail view at inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEG4k.jpg)

Briefly, I want this line to work with a variable called attachmentFile rather than writing "2020-01-01.xlsx"
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="attachmentFile"')

```
import smtplib,ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders

attachmentFile="2021-01-02.xlsx"
def send_mail():

  send_from= 'spotalert@****.com'
  send_to='deniz.yildirim@****.com'
  subject = 'Uygunsuz Punta Bildirimi'

  body_1='Merhaba\n'
  body_2= 'xxxxx Nolu Punta Tahribatli kontrolde uygunsuz cikmistir.\n'
  body_3='Uygunsuzluk sebebi =  xxxxxxx '      + 'Puntanin Bulundugu Posta :'+'\n'
  body_4= ' Bu otomatik bir maildir lutfen cevap vermeyiniz.\n'
  body_5='Uygunsuzlugun ciktigi tarih'+ '\n'


  text = body_1 + body_2 + body_3 + body_4 +body_5 
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['From'] = send_from
  msg['To'] = send_to
  msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
  msg['Subject'] = subject
  msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

  part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream") 
  part.set_payload(open(attachmentFile, "rb").read())
  encoders.encode_base64(part)
  part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="2021-01-02.xlsx"')
  msg.attach(part)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the second-last line in your code instead of:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="2021-01-02.xlsx"')
```

use this:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachmentFile)
```